# How do I get rid of fatal error in Zend Framework 3 "getting started" tutorial?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework3

I have been trying to get through the "getting started" tutorial for Zend Framework 3. It has been going well, but once I get to "Forms and Actions" things stop working.

The tutorial is here: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/forms-and-actions/

This is the error I keep getting:

> Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Form\Form::bindValues(array $values =
>   Array) must be compatible with Zend\Form\Fieldset::bindValues(array
>   $values = Array, ?array $validationGroup = NULL) in
>   ...\zendtest\vendor\zendframework\zend-form\src\Form.php on line 24

I get this after I have created AlbumForm.php, implemented **InputFilterAwareInterface** in Album.php, created the add.phtml view script and copied the needed logic in AlbumController.php. Everything has been copied from the tutorial.

I was not able to find anyone through Google that has had the same problem, so I must be doing something very wrong, but I can't see what it is.

Does anyone have an idea to what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused by the mismatch of the definitions of the **method** "**bindValues**" between the child class "Zend\Form\Form" and its parent "Zend\Form\Fieldset".

The definition of **"Zend\Form\Fieldset"** was changed since release 2.9.1([github link](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/commit/8991ddb1e9435a9a37240b138131bbf990951b9b#diff-bf24109586ef9fc93a5938f683958d82)), but for **"Zend\Form\Form"** since release 2.11.0([github link](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/commit/fbda16c3e87725ac64418e8578d167320855f20b#diff-2c77116739ece89c91385095c838f093)).

You probably have installed a release between those version >=2.9.1 and < 2.11.0. Run a **composer update** in your skeleton root to get the latest release(currently is 2.11.0) of Zend form package:

```
composer update
```

or

```
php /path/to/composer.phar update
```